# Is there any problem performing Sajda Sahw without committing any mistakes?

Tags: salat, mistake, sajda, sujud

Let's say I am confused with something in my prayer. So if I perform Sajda Sahw, is it okay?
or even if I am sure that no mistakes I've made, can I still perform Sajda Sahw?

Comment: Sujud Sahw is related to uncertainty if you are certain about having done things right it doesn't make sense to perform it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have doubt about whether you made a mistake, follow the feeling that is stronger. If you feel it is more likely that you made a mistake, perform sajdah sawh. Otherwise, skip it. This is for the csee where doubt arises during salah.

If you follow a doubt you are unsure about repeatedly, I have heard tat this is potentially following the waswas of Shaitan. So one should avoid it unless you are more sure. My personal thought is that this is to make you actually focus during salah, rather than just assuming you can make mistakes every time and that sadjah sawh will make up for them. That's a poor way of performing salah.

There's more here: https://islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/211

Allah knows best. May He guide us all.